# php script executes but no output

Tags: php

I have gone through all the similar questions and nothing fits the bill.

I am running a big script, which ran on chron on an old server but failed on the new so I am working on and testing in browser.

I have two functions, one pulls properties from the database, and then runs them through another which converts the price into 4 currencies, and if the value is different updates the row. The functions are as follows:

```
<?php

    function convert_price($fore_currency, $aft_currency, $amount)
    {
        echo "going into convert<br/>";
        $url = "http://www.currency.me.uk/remote/ER-ERC-AJAX.php?ConvertFrom=" . $fore_currency .
            "&ConvertTo=" . $aft_currency . "&amount=" . $amount;
        if (!is_int((int)file_get_contents($url))) {
            //echo "Failed on convert<br/>";
            return false;
        } else {
            //echo "Conversion done";
            return (int)file_get_contents($url);
        }
    }

    function run_conversion($refno = '', $output = false)
    {
        global $wpdb;
        $currencies = array("GBP", "EUR", "TRY", "USD");
        $q = "SELECT * FROM Properties ";
        $q .= (!empty($refno)) ? " WHERE Refno='" . $refno . "'" : "";
        $rows = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare($q), ARRAY_A);
        $currencies = array("USD", "GBP", "TRY", "EUR");
        //$wpdb->show_errors();
        echo "in Run Conversion " . "<br/>";
        foreach ($rows as $row) {
            echo "In ROw <br/>";
            foreach ($currencies as $currency) {
                if ($currency != $row['Currency'] && $row['Price'] != 0) {
                    $currfield = $currency . "_Price";
                    $newprice = convert_price($row['Currency'], $currency, $row['Price']);
                    echo "Old Price Was " . $row['Price'] . " New Price Is " . $newprice . "<br/>";
                    if ($newprice) {
                        if ($row[$currfield] != $newprice) {
                            $newq = "UPDATE Properties SET DateUpdated = '" . date("Y-m-d h:i:s") . "', " .
                                $currfield . "=" . $newprice . " WHERE Refno='" . $row['Refno'] . "'";
                            $newr = $wpdb->query($newq);
                            if ($output) {
                                echo $newq . " executed <br/>";
                            } else {
                                echo "query failed " . $wpdb->print_error();
                            }
                        } else {
                            if ($output) {
                                echo "No need to update " . $row['Refno'] . " with " . $newprice . "<br/>";
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        echo "Currency conversion failed";
                    }
                }

            }

        }

    }

?>
```

I then run the process from a seperate file for the sake of chron like so:

```
require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/functions.php"); // page containing functions
run_conversion('',true);
```

If I limit the mysql query to 100 properties it runs fine and I get all the output in a nice stream. But when I try to run it in full the script completes (I can see from rows updated in db) but no output. I have tried upping the memory allowance but no joy. Any ideas gratefully received. Also, I get a 500 error when changing from Apache Module to CGI. Any ideas on that also well received as ideally I would like to turn site onto fastCGI.

Comment: You should take a look at the error log.

Comment: `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` assumes HTTP and you mention Apache but you say it's a cron script. Is cron relevant here?

Comment: Are you sure it's completing _all_ of the updates? Could it be that the script is reaching the max_execution_time?

Comment: I have looked at error log, no error (it runs when I reduce the limit on the mysql query, so def memmory or timing) I have tried using ini_set to increase memory and set_time_limit(0) both to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

You're running out of memory most likely. Probably in your DB layer. Your best bet is to unset your iterative values at the end of each loop:

```
foreach ( $rows as $row ) {
    ...

    foreach ( $currencies as $currency ) {
        ...
        unset( $currency, $newr, $currfield, $newprice );
    }

    unset( $row );
}
```

This will definitely help.

Answer (score 0):

As another answer suggests you may be running out of memory, but if you make an HTTP call everytime the loop is running, and you have 100+ currencies, this may also cause the problem. Try limit it to 5 currencies for example.

If this is indeed the problem I would split the process, so a chunk of currencies have their respective value updated per cron job, instead of everything.